# Why is my button variable attaching to a specific element in my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var characters = [["Obi Wan Kenobi", 'obi', '120'], ["Luke Skywalker", 'luke', '100'], ["Darth Sidious", 'sidious', '150'], ["Darth Maul", 'maul', '180']];

for ( i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {

  // Inside the loop...

  // 2. Create a variable named "charBtn" equal to $("<button>");

  var charBtn = $("<pre><button></pre>");

  charBtn.addClass("char-button char col-md-3");
  charBtn.addClass(characters[i][1]);

  charBtn.attr("id", characters[i][1]);

  charBtn.text(characters[i][0] + "\n" + characters[i][2]);

  charBtn.css("height", "200px");
  charBtn.css("color", "black");
  charBtn.css("font-size", "25px");
  charBtn.css("font-weight", "bold");
  charBtn.css("text-align", "center");
  charBtn.css("padding-top", "100px");
  charBtn.css("-webkit-text-stroke", "1px red");

  $("#buttons").append(charBtn);
  console.log(charBtn);
}

$(".obi").on("click", function() { 
$("#selection").append(this);
$("#choices").append("<h3>Choose your enemy!</h3>");
$("#choices").append(charBtn, $("#luke"));
$("#choices").append(charBtn, $("#sidious"));
$("#choices").append(charBtn, $("#maul"));
console.log(charBtn);

$("#obi").unbind("click");
$("#luke").unbind("click");
$("#sidious").unbind("click");
$("#maul").unbind("click");

$(".luke").on("click", function() {
$("#defender").append((charBtn , $("#luke")));
$("#obi").unbind("click");
$("#luke").unbind("click");
$("#sidious").unbind("click");
$("#maul").unbind("click");
console.log(charBtn);
})
$(".sidious").on("click", function() {
$("#defender").append((charBtn , $("#sidious")));
$("#obi").unbind("click");
$("#luke").unbind("click");
$("#sidious").unbind("click");
$("#maul").unbind("click");
})
$(".maul").on("click", function() {
$("#defender").append((charBtn , $("#maul")));
$("#obi").unbind("click");
$("#luke").unbind("click");
$("#sidious").unbind("click");
$("#maul").unbind("click");
})

})

$(".maul").on("click", function() {
$("#selection").append(this);

$("#choices").append("<h3>Choose your enemy!</h3>");
$("#choices").append(charBtn, $("#luke"));
$("#choices").append(charBtn, $("#obi"));
$("#choices").append(charBtn, $("#sidious"));



$("#obi").unbind("click");
$("#luke").unbind("click");
$("#sidious").unbind("click");
$("#maul").unbind("click");

$(".luke").on("click", function() {
$("#defender").append((charBtn , $("#luke")));
$("#obi").unbind("click");
$("#luke").unbind("click");
$("#sidious").unbind("click");
$("#maul").unbind("click");
})
$(".obi").on("click", function() {
$("#defender").append((charBtn , $("#obi")));
$("#obi").unbind("click");
$("#luke").unbind("click");
$("#sidious").unbind("click");
$("#maul").unbind("click");
})
$(".sidious").on("click", function() {
$("#defender").append((charBtn , $("#sidious")));
$("#obi").unbind("click");
$("#luke").unbind("click");
$("#sidious").unbind("click");
$("#maul").unbind("click");
})

});
```

The problem that I am having is that the button variable "charBtn" that is being created on load is sticking to the last element in the array and I don't know why... 
In the first console log after I append the buttons to the button div it logs all four buttons created, but then in the next two logs I ran it only shows ".maul". I am pretty sure that because it was the last iteration in the loop, it is sticking to the variable. When I try to just append maul to the selection div and all the other buttons to the defenders div it drags maul to the defenders div as well. After commenting out the rest of them maul appends to the selection div by itself but if I then try to append the others to the defenders div it overrides maul and brings him down as well... Can anyone help explain why maul is sticking to the charBtn variable? Any solutions?

Ps. I understand this is hard coded in many ways I am still fairly new at javascript/jQuery I am still trying to get a grip on the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I just answered my own question maybe I need the rubber ducky on my desk...
The reason this is happening is because I am recycling the variable charBtn in the loop, so yes it is sticking to the last iteration. When I reference it down below to append to the div there is no need to call the variable like I am doing in..

```
$(".maul").on("click", function() {
$("#selection").append(this);

$("#choices").append("<h3>Choose your enemy!</h3>");
$("#choices").append(charBtn, $("#luke"));
$("#choices").append(charBtn, $("#obi"));
$("#choices").append(charBtn, $("#sidious"));
```

I can delete charBtn out of that segment of code and just reference the id like this...

```
  $(".maul").on("click", function() {
  $("#selection").append(this);
  $("#choices").append("<h3>Choose your enemy!</h3>");
  $("#choices").append($("#luke"));
  $("#choices").append($("#obi"));
  $("#choices").append($("#sidious"));
```

If you have any tips on how I could go about not hardcoding this so much that would be greatly appreciated.